# Is there an easy way to find two values that, when multiplied together, produce an exact bit pattern?

Tags: c++, testing, multiplication

For testing purposes, I need to find two 64-bit integer values that exactly multiply to a 128-bit intermediate value with a specific bit pattern.  Obviously, I can generate the desired intermediate value and divide by random values until I find a combination that works, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: "random values"?  How about "prime factors"?  That would make more sense, wouldn't it?  Or is there something about simple prime factorization that doesn't apply here?

Comment: Well the output values need to lie within a certain range.  Specifically this is for floating point testing, so for a floating point value with a M bit mantissa, I need the Mth bit set in the factors, so I can't just rely on prime factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem sounds like [integer factorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).  No fast algorithms are known unfortunately, but from glancing at that Wikipedia page it seems there are some (possibly tricky) algorithms that are faster than trial division.

Comment: Indeed I had a feeling that was the case.  It's made even trickier by the fact that the two target variables have to fall within a given range.

Answer (score 4):

I was about to post the same thing as j_random_hacker.  I'll just add that if the 128-bit number is prime, or has a prime factor larger than 64 bits, then there will be no solution to your problem.

Comment: Fortunately I can just generate a new 128-bit value after a certain number of iterations have failed.  So that's a bonus.

Comment: Well, if you can generate new 128-bit values, then what's special about the values?  Wouldn't it be easier to generate 64-bit values and multiply them together?  If you need special characteristics in the 128-bit value, it's might be easier to figure out how to make 64-bit pairs of numbers that will multiply to a 128-bit value with the desired characteristics than to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

And I'll just add to previous comment: if 128 bit number has prime factor larger than 64 bits, then it certainly has a factor less than 64 bits :)